# Search through Postgresql using search bar, then display it

Tags: php, postgresql

**The Problem**

Hello, I am creating a search function that will allow users to search for a specific E-Number and see whether it is derived from animals or not, basically seeing if it's vegan. I have successflly connected to the database using PHP on my website but the pg_query.

**What I Want to Happen:**

I want a user to being able to search for an E-number in a seach bar like the example below:

[image]

There is four columns in the table, I want to allow the user to search through one, this being 'code', and then displaying an answer, this being the 'vegan' column in my database.

**The Code so far**

```
<?php       
    // Connecting, selecting database
    $dbconn = pg_connect("***** port=*****
        dbname=***** user=***** password=*****")
        or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());    

    // Performing SQL query
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM enumbers';
    $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

    // Printing results in HTML
    echo "<table>\n";
    while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "\t<tr>\n";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
            echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

Comment: And whats the problem?

Comment: Instead of just printing everything out, how would I go about creating a search bar, I cannot find any helpful tutorials on this.

Comment: Simply change your SQL query. Look at the `WHERE` clause. You can do something like `SELECT * FROM enumbers WHERE code = input` - Simply google for SQL WHERE and you'll find tons of examples :)

Comment: Ahh, brilliant, thank you Twinfriends

Comment: No problem. Recommend you to google, try it by yourself and if you can't achieve what you want, edit your question and comment again, so I'll have a look at it. Also, please look at http://bobby-tables.com for more information about SQL injection, so you can insert a prepared statement. Otherwise your application will run at a high risk of SQL injection.